# If connection is closed by a Database, do I need to close it manually?

Tags: java, jdbc, garbage-collection, connection, connection-pooling

I have a connection pool. In the `getConnection()` method I poll a connection from the queue to a variable and check whether it is closed by `isClosed()` method. If it is closed I set to the variable new connection by `DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password)` method.

The question is: do I need to close the connection mannualy by `close()` method before rewriting the varible to ensure that the connection will be collected by the Garbage Collector?

Comment: connection is already close, so what are you going to get out of calling close again.. nothing?

Comment: Maybee the close method doing something else. I was told that the Garbage Collectore do not collect conections if they are not closed.

Comment: You were told wrong. But `isClosed()` doesn't mean the connection was closed by the database. It means *you* closed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not needed `(Recommended)`.

If you call `close()` manually after the connection has been closed, there will be no action performed on that connection object.

Comment: If you can call `isClosed` on a connection then the connection obviously has not been garbage collected...